# Notation for rounding in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm wondering if there is a symbol or notation for `Round to the nearest 10th`

For example, the area of a circle with a radius of 45 feet, rounded to the nearest square foot, could be written as, `A = π45²sym`

Where `sym` is some symbol that means round to the nearest sq foot

Comment: No the formula to find the area is A = π r². I want a symbol that means and then round to x

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll fix that

Answer (score 13):

There isn't a simple notation for that.  In the past fifty years or so the notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ has become common to mean the greatest integer that is not more than $x$.   For example $\lfloor 8.9\rfloor = \lfloor 8.5 \rfloor = \lfloor 8.2 \rfloor = \lfloor 8 \rfloor = 8$.

The result of rounding $x$ to the *nearest* integer is $$\left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor.$$

If you want to round to the nearest 10, you can then do $$10\left\lfloor \frac x{10}+\frac12\right\rfloor$$ which rounds $\frac{x}{10}$ to the nearest integer, then multiplies by 10 again.  Replacing the 10 with something else such as 17 will round to the nearest multiple of 17 or whatever; in particular $$\frac1{10}\left\lfloor 10x+\frac12\right\rfloor$$
 will round to the nearest tenth.

Comment: so. 10⌊423.3⌋ = 420?

Comment: No. $\lfloor 423.3\rfloor = 423$.  To round $423.3$ to the nearest ten you use $$10\left\lfloor\frac{423.3}{10}+\frac12\right\rfloor = 10\lfloor 42.33 + 0.5 \rfloor = 10 \lfloor 42.83 \rfloor = 10\cdot 42 = 420.$$

Comment: Ok so it's probably just easier to use words.

Comment: I agree.  Not everything needs to be written with symbols.

Answer (score 11):

I have come across the following notation: $\lfloor 12.3 \rceil=12$ or $\lfloor 12.7 \rceil=13$.

I think that I have seen it in the "Concrete Mathematics" book by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik.Anyway that notation combines neatly the ceiling and floor function. However, I wouldn't say that it has become a standard notation yet.

Comment: Looks too much like 「Japanese」 quotations (equivalents of “”)

Comment: Good notation; however, I couldn't find this notation after doing a Ctrl+F in Graham et al's *Concrete Mathematics* for *round* and *"nearest integer"*.

Comment: The similar notation $\lceil x\rfloor$ is used in pp. 43 and 260 of Flajolet and Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics* (Cambridge University Press, 2009).

Comment: cf. [Bart's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3353812/279330)

Comment: In my opinion I think $[x]$ is clearer than $⌊x⌉$. If you have a big nested expression and you only see the left $⌊$ you might think it is part of a floor function and you would have to parse the expression carefully before you would notice it is actually a round function. Then again, it might be confused for regular square brackets. I think it's weird that such a common function doesn't have proper standard notation yet.

Answer (score 2):

I like the combined floor/ceiling symbol for nearest integer, although Wolfram calls it "cumbersome"  and "not recommended". 
When I was at school, if you wanted to show an answer was rounded to the nearest 10th, you'd put "(to 1dp)" after it, where "dp" stands for "decimal place". An alternative approach to rounding was "(to 3 sf)" where "sf" means "significant figures". 
Eg
12345.67 = 12345.6 (to 1 dp) or 12300 (to 3 sf)
12.34567 = 12.3 (to 1 dp) or 12.3 (to 3 sf)