# Is there an icon latin, glyph or symbol that means rounding?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, floating-point, rounding-unit

Is there an icon that means rounding? I'm not talking about notation but specifically an icon, glyph or symbol.

For example, "pi" has the icon $\pi$.

I would also accept an icon that means integer (as opposed to decimal).

I was looking at this character $\sigma$ (SIGMA) or this one ≈: or $\Omega$ (GREEK OMEGA). All of these are in the Mac Character Viewer in Math Symbols. I mention these specifically so that I'm not using a character that means something already.

The goal is to round a number with $2$ decimal points to a whole number. It can use standard rounding properties. The user is given a number and sometimes it has $2$ decimal places. Some people want to round the number. Rounding up or down does not matter the wholeness does.

**Related Operating System Character Viewer:**

[image]

Related question for reference:
[Notation for rounding in equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681252/notation-for-rounding-in-equation)

Comment: Widespread use has $[x]$ for the integer part and $\{x\}$ for the fractional part. This is simple enough to type that there is no need for more complicated notations with additional symbols.

Comment: Even more widespread is the use of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for the integer part.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) for some.

Comment: I'm making a button that means "Round the number".

Comment: @PrimeMover Notice that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer smaller or equal to $x$ (so for instance $\lfloor 1.9\rfloor=1$ and $\lfloor -1.9\rfloor=-2$, which isn't  what we commonly call rounding (which is often to nearest integer, either half-up or half-away-from-zero).

Comment: @Gae.S. the wiki page it has mentions ≈:. would that be better?

Comment: If it were a calculator I have to buy, I would just want a button with "round" for the rounding to nearest integer. But I guess I'm not from Asia.

Comment: @Gae.S. Agreed. I'm designing a UI that has limited space. I'll add that as the tool tip.

Comment: @Gae.S. MY comment was in reply to Lutz Lehmann who was discussing the integer part.

Comment: You guys are great thanks

Comment: @PrimeMover Ah, ok. I thought that it was important for 1.21 giagawatts' sake to point out that referring to any notation for the floor or ceiling function wasn't an answer to his question and, if adopted as a solution to his problem, it would be counterproductive.

Comment: Is `#.##` short enough for the button? Such or similar is sometimes used to indicate rounding to two decimals (resp. producing the string for the rounded value).

Comment: @LutzLehmann I remind you that rounding to $n$ decimal places is a less useful operation than rounding to $n$ significant figures. The former does not scale when you change units (e.g. $3.48$ cm to $2$ d.p. is not $34.8$ mm to $2$ s.f., but $3.48$ cm to $3$ s.f. is still $34.8$ mm to $3$ s.f.) hence IMO it's usually "best" when discussing generic rounding to talk about significant figures rather than decimal places. TL;DR: dp rounding is "freshman", sf is "sophomore".

Comment: @PrimeMover : The question was for a recognizable symbol for a button. What a sensible implementation of that functionality is is a vastly more complex question. The answer to that question can be hinted at in a tooltip and more comprehensively in the documentation, and possibly includes option selection similar to the degree-radians switch.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that any symbol for "round" must incorporate the following options:

a) Are you rounding to "decimal places" or "significant figures"?

b) How many digits, of either "decimal places" or "significant figures"?

c) What sort of rounding: half-up, half-down, or half-to-nearest-even? (There may be other options.)

So whatever symbolism is needed, it must be capable of communicating all these options so that the user understands exactly what is meant. Rounding is a surprisingly non-trivial exercise.

Comment: OK good point. I was looking at this character `` (SIGMA) or this one `≈:` or Ω (GREEK OMEGA). All of these are in the Mac Character Viewer in Math Symbols. I mention these specifically so that I'm not using a character that means something already.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It might be an idea to add whatever information like this in the body of the question, then, so that we all have full understanding of teh context in which you are working. Specify in your question whether this is in the context of a calclator you're building, or a mathematical exposition you are writing, or a specific computer that you want to implement it on, stuff like that. Then we know what we are going to be expected to answer.